# Atomic layer deposition applications?

Tags: physical-chemistry

What unexplored areas (known unknowns) are there in atomic layer deposition (ALD)? What unexplored applications of ALD are there? It seems like people use it a lot for coatings of either insulators or sometimes transparent conducting contacts. What else could you do with it?

Answer (score 2):

"Other applications with similar demanding requirements outside of the semiconductor industry are low electron leakage dielectrics for magnetic read/write heads... and diffusion barrier coatings with low gas permeability..." (http://chem.colorado.edu/georgegroup/images/stories/300.pdf )

Comment: Oh neat! I didn't realize that diffusion barriers for gas could be made with ALD, but I suppose it makes sense in hindsight. I will check that out. Very cool! Do you think plasma be contained? Plasma could ionize the atomic-layer-deposited gas diffusion barrier.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have an opinion on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for the unknown part of your question but it is also used for semiconductors and photopholtaic panels.

Comment: More specifically, it's used to deposit HfO2 in advanced 45nm and smaller tech nodes. Probably it's the most money-generating application of ALD :-)